# CPA security of a stateless and deterministic encryption system

Tags: encryption, chosen-plaintext-attack, deterministic-encryption

Why can no stateless and deterministic encryption system be IND-CPA secure?

Is there a formal proof for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the answer for why a deterministic public-key encryption scheme cannot be CPA secure.

For CPA security it is sufficient if an adversary can distinguish between encryptions of two messages $m_0$ and $m_1$. That is, an adversary gets to see an encryption $c \gets \textsf{Enc}(pk,m_b)$ for a random bit $b$ together with the public key $pk$. Now in order to figure out if $c$ is an encryption of $m_0$ all the adversary has to do is to recompute $\textsf{Enc}(pk,m_0)$ and check whether or not this value matches the given ciphertext thus breaking CPA security.

Comment: Essentially the same argument also works for symmetric ciphers, since the definition of [IND-CPA security](http://crypto.cs.uiuc.edu/wiki/index.php/IND-CPA_security) assumes that the attacker has access to an encryption oracle.

Comment: @Ilmari, looks like the link to CPA definition is broken.

Comment: @doughgle: So it seems. [Archive.org to the rescue.](http://web.archive.org/web/20160507221932/http://crypto.cs.uiuc.edu/wiki/index.php/IND-CPA_security)